# Нарушение доступа для чтения. Язык Си

Tags: c, visual-studio

Проблема, которую я изложу ниже появилась у меня при попытках написать код дерева двоичного поиска. Весь код я по возможности описал комментариями.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct treeNode
{
    struct treeNode* left;
    int data;
    struct treeNode* right;
} TREENODE;

//ПРЯМОЙ ОБХОД ЭЕЛЕМЕНТОВ
void preOrder(TREENODE* tree)
{
    if (tree != NULL)
    {
        printf("%3d ", tree->data);
        preOrder(tree->left);
        preOrder(tree->right);
    }
}



//ПОИСК УЗЛА ПО ЕГО МЕТКЕ В ДДП
TREENODE* searchNode(TREENODE* tree, int value)
{
    TREENODE* q = tree;/*указатель на текущий узел*/
    /*цикл поиска узла*/
    while (q != NULL)
    {
        if (q->data == value)
            break;/*нашли узел и выходим из цикла*/
        else
        {
            if (value < q->data)/*если число меньше, нужно двигаться влево*/
                q = q->left;
            else /*если число больше, нужно двигаться вправо*/
                q = q->right;
        }
    }
    /*вышли из цикла поиска элемента*/
    if (q == NULL)
    {
        puts("Not founded!");
        return NULL; /*узел не найден */
    }
    puts("Founded!");
    return q;/*узел найден */
}

//ВСТАВКА НОВОГО УЗЛА В ДДП
TREENODE* insertNode(TREENODE* tree, int value)
{
    TREENODE* newNode = (TREENODE*)malloc(sizeof(TREENODE));
    TREENODE* root = tree;
    if (newNode != NULL)
    {
        /*создали узел дерева*/
        newNode->data = value;
        newNode->left = NULL;
        newNode->right = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Error!");
    }
    if (root == NULL) /*пустое дерево*/
        return newNode;/*новый узел становиться корнем дерева*/
    while (root != NULL)
    {
        /*вставка в дерево*/
        if (value < root->data)
        {   /*если число меньше, нужно двигаться влево*/
            if (root->left != NULL)
                root = root->left;
            else
            {
                root->left = newNode;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (value > root->data)
        {
            /*если число больше, нужно двигаться вправо*/
            if (root->right != NULL)
                root = root->right;
            else
            {
                root->right = newNode;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            puts("Clone");
            break;
        }
    }
    return tree;
}


//УДАЛЕНИЕ УЗЛА ИЗ ДДП
TREENODE* deleteNode(TREENODE* tree, int value)
{
    TREENODE* q = tree;/*указатель на текущий узел*/
    TREENODE* parent = NULL;/*указатель на родителя*/
    TREENODE* s1, * s2, * s;/*указатели на сыновей*/
    TREENODE* max_node;/*указатель для поиска максимального элемента в правом поддереве*/
    int tmp;
    /*цикл поиска удаляемого узла*/
    while (q != NULL)
    {
        if (q->data == value)
            break;/*нашли узел и выходим из цикла*/
        else
        {
            parent = q;/*текущий узел это отец для следующего*/
            if (value < q->data)/*если число меньше, нужно двигаться влево*/
                q = q->left;
            else /*если число больше, нужно двигаться вправо*/
                q = q->right;
        }
    }
    /*вышли из цикла поиска элемента*/
    if (q == NULL)
    {
        puts("Not founded!");
        return tree; /*узел не найден и возвращаем указатель на дерево*/
    }
    s1 = q->left;
    s2 = q->right;
    if (s1 == NULL && s2 == NULL)/*если удаляемый узел лист*/
    {
        if (parent != NULL)/*не корень дерева*/
        {
            /*обнуляем у отца ссылку на удаляемый узел*/
            if (parent->left == q)
                parent->left = NULL;
            else parent->right = NULL;
        }
        else/*удаление корня дерева*/
        {
            free(q);
            return NULL;/*дерево пустое*/
        }
    }
    else if (s1 == NULL || s2 == NULL)/*если только один сын у удаляемого узла*/
    {
        s = (s1 == NULL) ? s2 : s1;/*находим сына*/
        if (parent != NULL)/*не корень дерева*/
        {
            /*обнуляем у отца ссылку на удаляемый узел*/
            if (parent->left == q)
                parent->left = s;
            else parent->right = s;
        }
        else/*удаление корня дерева*/
        {
            free(q);
            return s;/*новый корень дерева*/
        }
    }
    else/*удаление узла у которого два сына*/
    {
        /*удаление происходит замещением*/
        /*ищем в левом поддереве самый правый узел
        - он является самым максимальным из всех узлов правого поддерева
        - для замены удаляемого узла*/
        max_node = q->left;
        while (max_node->right != NULL)
        {
            max_node = max_node->right;
        }
        tmp = max_node->data;/*копируем значение максимального узла из правого поддерева*/
        tree = deleteNode(tree, tmp);/*удалим замещающий узел*/
        q->data = tmp;/*копируем значение максимального узла из правого поддерева в удаляемый*/
        return tree;
    }
    free(q);
    return tree;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int a, b, c;
    char key;
    struct TREENODE tree;
    while (1) {
        system("cls");
        puts("1 - Добавление нового узла.");
        puts("2 - Удаление узла.");
        puts("3 - Поиск узла.");
        puts("4 - Вывод элементов.");
        puts("Для выхда нажмите ESC...");
        key = getchar();
        switch (key) {
        case '1':
            puts("Введите число.");
            scanf("%d", &a);
            insertNode(&tree, a);
            break;
        case '2':
            puts("Выберите число для удаления.");
            scanf("%d", &b);
            deleteNode(&tree, b);
            break;
        case '3':
            puts("Выберите элемент для поиска.");
            scanf("%d", &c);
            searchNode(&tree, c);
            break;
        case '4':
            preOrder(&tree);
            break;
        case 27:
            puts("Выход.");
            exit(0);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка компиляции на VS Code или на онлайн компиляторах заключается в том, как я понимаю, что в переменной root хранится какой-то мусор, так как при сравнении root с null выдает ошибку: "Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. root было 0xCCCCCCCC." Например, в строке `if (value < root->data)` в функции прямого обхода элементов вылазит данная ошибка. Самое интересное, что на QT Creator эта программа работает без каких либо проблем, исключений и ошибок. Я попробовал решить данную проблему, путем замены NULL значением 0xCCCCCCCC, и это вроде как работает, но это не точно.
Например я заменил вот так:

```
//ВСТАВКА НОВОГО УЗЛА В ДДП
TREENODE* insertNode(TREENODE* tree, int value)
{
    TREENODE* newNode = (TREENODE*)malloc(sizeof(TREENODE));
    TREENODE* root = tree;
    if (newNode != NULL)
    {
        /*создали узел дерева*/
        newNode->data = value;
        newNode->left = NULL;
        newNode->right = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Error!");
    }
    if (root == 0xCCCCCCCC) /*пустое дерево*/
        return newNode;/*новый узел становиться корнем дерева*/
    while (root != 0xCCCCCCCC)
    {
        /*вставка в дерево*/
        if (value < root->data)
        {   /*если число меньше, нужно двигаться влево*/
            if (root->left != 0xCCCCCCCC)
                root = root->left;
            else
            {
                root->left = newNode;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (value > root->data)
        {
            /*если число больше, нужно двигаться вправо*/
            if (root->right != 0xCCCCCCCC)
                root = root->right;
            else
            {
                root->right = newNode;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            puts("Clone");
            break;
        }
    }
    return tree;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так сделал, или что я не понимаю правильно.
Скриншот с примером одной ошибки прилагается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что это `root == 0xCCCCCCCC`??? И зачем? Что вы делаете, чтобы получить такую ошибку?

Comment: Попробую объяснить на примере функции вставки элемента в дерево. 
`if (root == NULL) /*пустое дерево*/ 
return newNode;/*новый узел становиться корнем дерева*/ 
while (root != NULL) 
{ /*вставка в дерево*/`
С самого начала программы по неизвестной мне причине в переменной root находится какой-то мусор размером 0xCCCCCCCC.  Я отталкиваюсь от нулевого значения, соответственно если я сравниваю root с NULL, то у меня вылазит ошибка (пример на скриншоте). Для этого я решил использовать "в качестве NULL" значение 0xCCCCCCCC как максимально приближенное к нулю.

Comment: Мусор в нем т.к. вы пишите `TREENODE tree;`, так что или инициализируйте в `main` начало дерева, или используйте указатель по типу `TREENODE* tree = NULL` и передавайте в функции без `&`. Так же если `root == NULL`, то просто вернется `newNode` и никакой вставки не произойдет

Comment: прошу прощения, изначально выложил не совсем верный код, структура у меня была проинициализирована таким образом: `struct TREENODE tree;`

Comment: Так же если root == NULL, то просто вернется newNode и никакой вставки не произойдет ----- Вы правы, я избавился от &, и программа начала компилироваться без исключений. Теперь буду работать над этой частью кода: "Так же если root == NULL, то просто вернется newNode и никакой вставки не произойдет"

Comment: Т.к. у вас переменная создается в `main` без инициализации, то в неё будет записан мусор, попробуйте создать её вне `main` и в неё будет записано значение по умолчанию для типа создаваемой переменной. Но `root` не будет `== NULL` так что в любом случае лучше работать с `TREENODE* tree = NULL`